# Sending numerous files via HTTP POST & curl

Tags: php, curl, file-transfer

**Problem :**

I am having difficulty with reliably sending numerous files via HTTP Post from one web server to another.

I've noticed the success of files being transferred over is dependent on the size and amount of files I choose to send.

What I constitute as a successful transfer is if all files sent from the source server appear in the directory of the receiving server.

```
//sender script

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
    'file1' => '@/var/www/html/uploadtest/largerfile.zip',
    'file2' => '@/var/www/html/uploadtest/largerfile.zip',
    'file3' => '@/var/www/html/uploadtest/smallerfile.zip'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com/test/reciever.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch)){
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

echo $res;

//recieving script

print_r($_FILES); //outputs as blank array on failed transfer
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "file1.zip" );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "file2.zip" );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "file3.zip" );
```

With the current files being sent across none of them arrive at their destination. If I remove one *largerfile.zip* then the file transfer is successful.

I am looking for error responses by printing *$res* but I don't see any despite a failed transfer. *curl_errno* also does not detect anything.

**Background :**

I've been recommended to use FTP previously but the Web API I'll be using only accepts POST. It's also likely that the files I need to transfer are around 50mbs.

I've also tried changing the following php.ini settings to :

- post_max_size : 100M
- upload_max_size : 60M

Comment: Not sure if this would help with your issue for sure, but you may want to look into `curl_multi_init`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: How long does it usually take before the transfer fails? Could it be related to the 60s timeout?

Comment: Are you uploading the files to your own server, or is the server you upload to not under your control?

Comment: @hakre The testing servers I am using are under my control but I the server I will eventually use will not be.

Comment: @AndersLindahl The transfer fails way before 60 seconds it usually fails around the same time for every failure. For example sending up two large files fails me at say around 10 seconds and sending up three large files fails me at around 10 seconds again. This time varies from which server I send files from.

Comment: Could it be a `max_execution_time` configuration in php? I'd run a sniffer on the traffic to sort out which end is deciding to tear down the connection, and continue looking there.

Comment: @AndersLindahl I've checked with phpinfo() on both ends and they have `max_execution_time` set as 120 (sender) and 30(reciever). I've also timed my PHP script from command line and this is the readout :

real 0m1.087s
user 0m0.012s
sys 0m0.016s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> It's also likely that the files I need to transfer are around 50mbs.

I assume you refer to the filesize on your harddisk per each file.

> `max_upload_size : 60M` (don't you mean `upload_max_filesize`?!)
>   `post_max_size : 100M`

There is a third setting related to file-uploads: [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). That is because those files will be loaded into memory before saved to disk on the server.

You want to transfer three files at once. Every file is about 50 mb. Let's just sum it up:

```
50 mb + 50 mb + 50 mb = 150 mb
```

That means:

- [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (!!) of 60 mb is too low, in case it counts for all three files at once (I can't remember from top of my head if that is the case or not).
- [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) of 100 mb is definitely too low, you will need a higher value here, at least `150m` and add a bit more on top. See [the manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) for more info.
- [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is unknown but it's highly like that it is too low, too.

For *testing* set `memory_limit` to `0` (unlimited) and play around with `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to match your needs.

I hope this helps you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I think this has done the trick.. my `memory_limit` was set abnormally low on my receiving server.